# Hotkeys still don't work in Java applications on non-latin keyboard layout

Tags: java

It seems that this trouble is from early 2010's but  none of  walkarounds which I found so far does not work in Elemenary OS 6 in 2021.

My main application of interest is Jetbrains Intellij Idea. Jetbrains even added switch in Idea's keymap settings which is related to this problem according to its title. However it has no effect in eOS 6.

Would you please tell me how such
inconvenient and rather critical for any Java-developer issue could be fixed. I'm ready to provide any additional details of my eOS 6 configuration (almost default settings) for further elaboration.

Non-java apps seems to work fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is an elementary OS issue? Have you confirmed it works fine on Ubuntu 20.04? If it's also a problem on Ubuntu, you'll have much better luck finding the answer on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @m93a for now I have only elementaryOs installed on my daily-driver laptop... Overall this distro is fine and switching to Ubuntu is not an option. Maybe I could check this out on Ubuntu LiveCD, but I'm not sure that I can install Intellij on LiveCD...

Comment: @m93a,
there are some topics on AskUbuntu related to this issue. All are rather outdated. For example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013410/keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-for-intellij

Comment: According to Jetbrains answer - in Ubuntu 21.04 Gnome hotkeys are working: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275243